# Combine 2 pages into one page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement that 2 existing pages need to be displayed in a single page.

Is there a way to combine these two existing pages into a single page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll have to copy the components manually to the target page, Apex can’t do it for you.